# How to access Qlabel under current layout on button click?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2, pyside6

Hii on QPushButton click I want to access QLabel value under current layout and set it in QLineEdit under same current layout in the following example :

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
    for x in range(0, 9):
        layout1.addLayout(nested_layout())
    window = QWidget()
    window.setLayout(layout1)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

def nested_layout():
    name_0_lineEdit = QLineEdit()
    name_0_label = QLabel('0')
    name_0_label.setHidden(True)
    name_0_button = QPushButton("Delete")
    name_0_button.clicked.connect(set_value)

    layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_lineEdit)
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_label)
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_button)
    return layout2

def set_value():
    # Access label value in current layout and show it in QLineEdit widget in the same layout
    print("Clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can we do this I could'nt find any reference or solution to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda to call the set_value function with the label and linedit widgets as parameters to the callback.

For example:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
    for x in range(0, 9):
        layout1.addLayout(nested_layout())
    window = QWidget()
    window.setLayout(layout1)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

def nested_layout():
    name_0_lineEdit = QLineEdit()
    name_0_label = QLabel('0')
    name_0_label.setHidden(True)
    name_0_button = QPushButton("Delete")
    name_0_button.clicked.connect(lambda: set_value(name_0_lineEdit, name_0_label))
    layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_lineEdit)
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_label)
    layout2.addWidget(name_0_button)
    return layout2

def set_value(lineedit, label):
    text = label.text()
    lineedit.setText(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However I highly recommend you look into subclassing and OOP approach to GUI programming... they allow much more flexibility than the procedural approach

Comment: Thanks bro the solution worked. for the sake of scenario that I needed solution with I wrote a simple example otherwise  I am using OOP based approach.